# CSS menu item getting misaligned

Tags: html, css, web, stylesheet

I have this CSS menu strip: http://jsfiddle.net/CgGBL/1/

[image]

It works fine, but if I try to use an image that is a bit larger on the first <li> the first menu item gets misaligned. For example, I added this height and width to the image's tag:

```
height="20" width="22"
```

... now the first menu item is misaligned (even though the image is still smaller than the first <li> height and width):

[image]

How can I fix my code to allow me to use a larger image and keep all menu items aligned?

Comment: Have you tried using `max-height` or `max-width`?

Comment: @AfzaalAhmadZeeshan: Where?

Comment: 1. You should use the `max-height` for the container div. So that this should not exceed. Then you should try to make sure the image always uses a percentage of the container i.e `li`. This way you will control the image size.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is due the anchor's css position.
Include the following style to ".div_mn ul li a":

```
display: block;
```

And reduce the padding top and bottom in anchors with img inside.

```
<a href="#" style="padding-top: 7px; padding-bottom: 7px;"><img height="20" width="22" src="http://images.wikia.com/uncyclopedia/images/7/7d/Icons-flag-us.png" alt="Smiley face" /> </a>
```

The final code:

http://jsfiddle.net/MxtK6/

Hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

add to your li items next code

```
li {
display: block;
float: left;
}
```

This must prevent your issue

Answer (score 0):

While increasing the height of the image add inline style to the li to reduce the top padding
that will fix your problem

**FIX**

```
<a href="#" style="font-size: 22; padding-top: 16px; padding-bottom:6px; width:100%; padding-left:"><img src="http://images.wikia.com/uncyclopedia/images/7/7d/Icons-flag-us.png" alt="Smiley face" height="20" width="22"  /> </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

you have to also give line-height in your anchor's tag

here is the complete solution
//HTML

```
<div class="div_mn">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#" style="padding-top: 7px; padding-bottom: 7px;"><img height="22" width="22" src="http://images.wikia.com/uncyclopedia/images/7/7d/Icons-flag-us.png" alt="Smiley face" /> </a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Mnu Itm 1</a>

    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Mnu Itm 2</a>

    </li>
</ul>
```

//CSS

```
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
 }
.div_mn {
text-align: center;
position: relative;
padding: 10px;
min-width: 200px;
}
.div_mn ul {
display: inline-block;
outline: none;
cursor: pointer;
text-align: center;
}
.div_mn ul li {
float: left;
list-style: none;
}
 .div_mn ul li a {
font-family: Arial;
font-size: 12px;
padding: 11px 35px;
text-decoration: none;
display: block;
color: #FFFFFF;
line-height:20px; ////give line height approx or exact your image height
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0176B4, #005e90 49%, #005e90 50%, #00527d);
background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0176B4, #005e90 49%, #005e90 50%, #00527d);
background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #0176B4, #005e90 49%, #005e90 50%, #00527d);
background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #0176B4, #005e90 49%, #005e90 50%, #00527d);
background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #0176B4, #005e90 49%, #005e90 50%, #00527d);
}
```

update [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MxtK6/2/)